# Regex to match as few many times as possible (lazy) using grep

Tags: regex, shell, command-line, terminal, grep

I'm quite new to regex. I have the following simple line in a txt file.

```
This one has some different PATTERNs, including PTTRN, and PTN, then it repeats PTTRN and PATTERN
```

Using `grep -E`, I want to match everything between the first PATTERN and the first PTTRN without extending the match to the second PTTRN.

I tried doing

```
PATTERN.*?PTTRN
```

That seems to work in https://regex101.com/r/qI4aA6/8

But when I try using it in the terminal with grep, it colours all the way down to the second PTTRN, that is

```
PATTERNs, including PTTRN, and PTN, then it repeats PTTRN
```

Besides, I'm using the default grep (gnu grep) on my ubuntu system.

Comment: Did you use `grep -P` ?

Comment: It works with the -P option, but what I really want is doing it with the -E option (extended regex)... I forgot mentioning it. I'm new to regex so I didn't realize there was a difference between Perl regex and Extended regex. Anyway, thx

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-P` (PCRE) flag with gnu-grep:

```
grep -oP 'PATTERN.*?PTTRN' file
PATTERNs, including PTTRN
```

Or else on BSD `grep`:

```
grep -oE 'PATTERN.*?PTTRN' file
PATTERNs, including PTTRN
```

Comment: As I said to the first comment to my post, It works with the -P option, but what I really want is doing it with the -E option (extended regex)... I'm new to regex so I didn't realize there was a difference between Perl regex and Extended regex. Besides, I'm using gnu-grep. I'm going to change the question.

Comment: gnu-grep doesn't like **lazy** quantifier so `-P` is the only option there or else use awk.